# Updating Ubuntu machine manually that cannot be connected to internet

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I have a device running Ubuntu 18.04 that cannot be connected to the internet.

I would like to be able to update and install packages, but the standard `apt update`, `apt upgrade`, and `apt install` commands will not work.

What I believe I would need to do is run a command on the machine to collect what packages have been installed, take that information to another ubuntu machine to determine what packages are out of date and need to be updated, request the the packages to be updated or installed, and then take those packages back to the device and point apt at them.

I assume this need is not necessarily uncommon and there is a standard procedure for accomplishing it. How can I do this?

Comment: Use the tool `apt-offline` - see [How to Update or Upgrade Ubuntu Offline without Internet](https://www.debugpoint.com/2021/03/how-to-update-or-upgrade-ubuntu-offline-without-internet/)

Comment: sadly, the tool doesn't appear to work for the simplest use case. I have filed a bug. https://github.com/rickysarraf/apt-offline/issues/145